# Embed dotnet core (.NET Core) into native applications on Windows/Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, coreclr, .net-core

Are there possibilities to embed dotnet core (.NET Core) environments into native processes?

My use-case would be an existing game-server where I want to offer the possibility to extend the game using C# on .NET Core on both Windows and Linux.

Bonus question: would there also be an `AppDomain`-concept available like in "oldschool" .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

I found this documentation with examples:
[.NET Core Hosting Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting)

If the link does not work anymore, search the web for "hosting .NET Core".

About AppDomains ... I guess not.
If you use CoreClrHost.h you can provide an ID for the default AppDomain, but it seems to be the one and only AppDomain. For isolation you can use seperate processes. Maybe AssemblyLoadContext class can also be a help to you.

Answer (score 0):

AppDomain is not coming to dotnet core. Parts of the AppDomain api will come over, but nothing directly related to the functionality you speak of. I don't believe you can embed dotnet core applications inside a native process, however inside of a native process you could boot a dotnet core process.

Answer (score 0):

And I have tested embedded gui or windowing system and you can embed into static executable. First use Alpine or Void-Linux ( qemu guest via shared folder ) See more info https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/issues/2202

Sorry I will improve my answer after my work. Okay. I will explain you how do you embed gui or game layer framework like glfw or sdl2/3 but I use musl-gcc and dotnet application ues native aot. I hope you have experience about Alpine or Void-Linux.

// EDIT:

`AppDomain` -> `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
But it works for Net 8.0 - You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

If you want load native library ( built in dotnet library ) You need to pass `sbyte*`

You should to use `DeafMan1983.COnversion`

Example:

```
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "SayHello")]
public static void SayHello(sbyte* message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(StringFromSbytePointer(message));
}
```

And you pass project console with loading and passing library like `dlopen`, `dlsym`, `dlclose` and `dlerror`

Sorry I use only Linux - If you use Windows thzan you can pass `LoadLibraryEx`, `GetProcAddress`, `FreeLibrary` and more...

You can check example AppWithPlugin for NativeAot from my [repository](https://github.com/DeafMan1983/AppWithPluginForNativeAot) and enjoy your happy coding!

I hope that my repository helps your C# into native application :)